# fuse melt/dcast in one step

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
testdt <- data.table(var1=rep(c("a", "b"), e=3), p1=1:6, p2=11:16)
#   var1 p1 p2
#1:    a  1 11
#2:    a  2 12
#3:    a  3 13
#4:    b  4 14
#5:    b  5 15
#6:    b  6 16
```

I need to have the median value of each `var1` for each `p*`, the `p*` should be in rows and the different unique values of `var1` in columns.
So, I'm looking for this output:

```
 variable  a  b
1       p1  2  5
2       p2 12 15
```

The simplest way I found to get it is:

```
dcast(melt(testdt, id.vars = "var1", measure.vars = c("p1", "p2")),
      variable ~ var1,
      value.var = "value",
      fun.aggregate = median)
```

But I have a feeling I'm missing something here (like the most suited function) so I'd love to know a direct way (unique function) to do the same.

I'm aware `recast` of the *reshape2* package could do the trick with `recast(testdt, variable~var1, fun=median, id.var="var1")`, but I'd like to avoid loading another package.

***Edit:***

*I'm looking for a solution both simple and efficient. This would be applied on a list of ~40 tables with ~300 columns and ~80 rows*

Comment: Try `testdt[,lapply(.SD, median) , var1]` but this is the transpose of what you wanted.

Comment: thanks @akrun, already tried that but I need the "transpose" part

Comment: I assume this is *not* performance-related. Is that correct?

Comment: @AnandaMahto hi Ananda :-) Actually, the faster the better... (I will do that for 36 data.tables, in a list, having ~(100-300) columns x(1 to 10) rows )

Comment: `recast` in "reshape2" is just a `melt` + `dcast` anyway, which is why I was asking.

Comment: @AnandaMahto then maybe I'll just stick to melt + dcast ? what do you think, in term of efficiency, is it the best way ?

Comment: @Cath I'm confused now. What exactly is your goal? Code simplicity, which can be achieved by defining a custom function (after all, e.g., `melt` can only be considered simple because you don't see the actual code), or maximum performance?

Comment: @Roland, thanks for your comment, actually, I'm looking for the best ratio simplicity/efficiency: I need something easy to maintain on a long-term basis but which also runs fast. I thought `melt/dcast` was more efficient than `lapply(.SD...)/t` but I may be totally wrong on that. And I thought there might be some simple, efficient and unique function that would do the trick...

Comment: maybe it's time for me to do some benchmarking...

Comment: @Cath Yep. If performance is important you should provide relevant information (such as the expected size of the data). An example people can benchmark against would be best.

Comment: Those dimensions you describe should be a matter of milliseconds for data.table, no matter what approach you use. I don't think you're going to run into any performance problems there (unless you forgot to include a k or an M or something in there....)

Comment: @AnandaMahto thanks! I wouldn't expect less from `data.table` ;-); then I guess, the matter is just simplicity :-)

Comment: I'd personally go with your current approach. I don't know if performance is improved by specifying the measure variables, as you've done here, or not. (Unless, of course, there are other variables beyond the id and measure variables.)

Comment: @AnandaMahto, no, no other variables. I'm keeping the melt/dcast way for now then. Thanks :-)

Comment: Filed as a [feature request on the *data.table* GH repository](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1511).

Answer (score 1):

If speed is a primary concern, there is a slight speed boost of around 23% (although in milliseconds) if you calculate the `median` first.  This delta is also likely to increase as the size of your data set grows as there is less data to melt.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(testdt[, lapply(.SD, median), by=var1], id.vars="var1"), variable ~ var1))
```

benchmark

```
Unit: milliseconds

expr                         min       lq    mean   median       uq      max neval
fun.aggregate = median  4.221654 4.453063 4.87418 4.510775 4.579718 35.28569  1000
lapply(.SD, median)     3.196289 3.410711 3.77483 3.461073 3.523096 22.78637  1000
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'll study it better later I'm not with a pc now